# Mongoose: findByIdAndUpdate method is not updating nor inserting

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The findByIdAndUpdate method should update or insert an object in the DB, but it does nothing. Nor it does throw an error message or something.

I also tried it with the original ObjectId as _id field, but doesn't work either.

Has anybody a clue what is missing to update or insert the object into the DB?

```
const schema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, { toJSON: { virtuals: true } });

const myJson = {
    "myobject": {
    "_id": 781586495786495,
    "name": "MyName"
  }
}
const MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', schema);
MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(myJson.myobject._id, myJson.myobject, { upsert: true });
```

Comment: Try this:
`MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(ObjectId(myJson.myobject._id), myJson.myobject, { upsert: true });`

Comment: Doesn't work: The application throws the error: ReferenceError: Schema is not defined. Also tried it with Schema.Types.Number.

Comment: You need:```const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = Mongoose.Schema;```

Also, why do you keep your _id into the schema, you don't need it since it is a mongo id.

Comment: This snippet doesn't include the require statements to keep it lean, but in the actual code these statements are included.

Comment: I don't let Mongo generate the _id field, because I get an unique key from the json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code and it actually works as intended. The reason why it doesn't return any errors nor does anything might be that you're not connected to the database at the time you're executing the operation on the model.

Please consider the following snippet, it worked for me.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testingcollection').then(() => {
   const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
      _id: {
            type: Number,
          required: true
      },
      name: {
          type: String,
          required: true
      }
   }, { toJSON: { virtuals: true } });

   const myJson = {
      "myobject": {
      "_id": 781586495786495,
      "name": "MyName"
    }
     };

   const MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', schema);
   MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(myJson.myobject._id, myJson.myobject, { upsert: true }).then(obj => {
      mongoose.connection.close();
   });
});
```

Comment: This call only returns the query A.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, options)  // returns Query

Comment: But this one executes it: A.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, options, callback)